# Measuring CoreGraphics performance on iOS with FPS

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics

Is there any canonical way to measure the performance of a `CATiledLayer` on iOS?  In opengl land, it's pretty straightforward to track the FPS, is there any similar trick with `UIScrollViews` and `CATiledLayers`?

For context, we're tweaking the images going into a `CATiledLayer` and noticing severe differences in the zooming FPS and panning FPS with the `UIScrollView`.  It's subjective but obvious and I was hoping there was a way to measure this so we can stop saying "wow, this seems a lot faster".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can profile your app with Instrument's Core Animation tool. It will give you the FPS reading.

[image]

Note that this is only available on device and not on simulator.